# read complicated format .txt file into Matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a txt file that I want to read into Matlab. Data format is like below:

```
term2 2015-07-31-15_58_25_612 [0.9934343, 0.3423043, 0.2343433, 0.2342323]
term0 2015-07-31-15_58_25_620 [12]
term3 2015-07-31-15_58_25_625 [2.3333, 3.4444, 4.5555]
...
```

How can I read these data in the following way?

```
name = [term2 term0 term3] or namenum = [2 0 3]
time = [2015-07-31-15_58_25_612 2015-07-31-15_58_25_620 2015-07-31-15_58_25_625]
data = {[0.9934343, 0.3423043, 0.2343433, 0.2342323], [12], [2.3333, 3.4444, 4.5555]}
```

I tried to use `textscan` in this way `'term%d %s [%f, %f...]'`, but for the last data part I cannot specify the length because they are different. Then how can I read it? My Matlab version is R2012b.

Thanks a lot in advance if anyone could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to do that in one single pass, but for me these kind of problems are easier to sort with a 2 pass approach.

- Pass 1: Read all the columns with a constant format according to their type (string, integer, etc ...) and read the non constant part in a separate column which will be processed in second pass.
- Pass 2: Process your irregular column according to its specificities.

In a case with your sample data, it looks like this:

```
%% // read file 
fid = fopen('Test.txt','r') ;
M = textscan( fid , 'term%d %s %*c %[^]] %*[^\n]'  ) ;
fclose(fid) ;

%% // dispatch data into variables
name = M{1,1} ;
time = M{1,2} ;
data = cellfun( @(s) textscan(s,'%f',Inf,'Delimiter',',') , M{1,3} ) ;
```

What happened:
The first `textscan` instruction reads the full file. In the format specifier:

- `term%d` read the *integer* after the literal expression `'term'`.
- `%s`     read a *string* representing the date.
- `%*c`    ignore one *character* (to ignore the character `'['`).
- `%[^]]`  read everything (as a *string*) until it finds the character `']'`.
- `%*[^\n]` ignore everything until the next newline (`'\n'`) character. (to not capture the last `']'`.

After that, the first 2 columns are easily dispatched into their own variable. The 3rd column of the result cell array `M` contains strings of different lengths containing different number of floating point number. We use [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) in combination with another [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the numbers in each cell and return a cell array containing `double`:

[image: textscan advanced]

---

Bonus:
If you want your time to be a numeric value as well (instead of a string), use the following extension of the code:

```
%% // read file 
fid = fopen('Test.txt','r') ;
M = textscan( fid , 'term%d %f-%f-%f-%f_%f_%f_%f %*c %[^]] %*[^\n]'  ) ;
fclose(fid) ;

%% // dispatch data
name = M{1,1} ;
time_vec = cell2mat( M(1,2:7) ) ;
time_ms  = M{1,8} ./ (24*3600*1000) ;   %// take care of the millisecond separatly as they are not handled by "datenum"
time = datenum( time_vec ) + time_ms ;
data = cellfun( @(s) textscan(s,'%f',Inf,'Delimiter',',') , M{1,end} ) ;
```

This will give you an array `time` with a Matlab time serial number (often easier to use than strings). To show you the serial number still represent the right time:

```
>> datestr(time,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF')
ans =
2015-07-31 15:58:25.612
2015-07-31 15:58:25.620
2015-07-31 15:58:25.625
```

Comment: So useful for me! Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

For comlicated string parsing situations like such it is best to use `regexp`. In this case assuming you have the data in file data.txt the following code should do what you are looking for:

```
txt = fileread('data.txt')
tokens = regexp(txt,'term(\d+)\s(\S*)\s\[(.*)\]','tokens','dotexceptnewline')

% Convert namenum to numeric type
namenum = cellfun(@(x)str2double(x{1}),tokens)

% Get time stamps from the second row of all the tokens
time = cellfun(@(x)x{2},tokens,'UniformOutput',false);

% Split the numbers in the third column 
data = cellfun(@(x)str2double(strsplit(x{3},',')),tokens,'UniformOutput',false)
```